# How do I pop a confirmation box like that of Gksudo when the user clicks a button?

Tags: gui

I have a hot corner set up that runs other commands to turn off my laptop's display and lock my screen. However, I often accidentally mouse into this hot corner. Is there any way of me setting up a popup box that gives the user a yes or no option before executing the commands to turn the display off? I'm looking for functionality almost like that of `gksudo`.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `zenity`or a similar dialog-like command:

```
zenity --yesno 'do you want to suspend?'
```

It asks the question in a dialog with 'yes' and 'no' buttons. Once you click one of those buttons, it prints the response on standard error (I believe). If you capture that, you can then have a script decide what to do based on the choice made by the user.

`zenity` has many more options for the dialog box; they're documented in the man page.

Comment: `zenity --yesno` is apparently an unavailable option. But I looked in man page and tried `--question`, and it did the trick. Just quick question, how do I use the input zenity gives in an if statement in bash?

Comment: The exit state: `zenity --question && echo "ok, will continue" || echo "okay, won't continue then"`

Comment: for an if statement, that's `if zenity --question; then`. The `test` command (aka `[`) is, after all, *also* just a command whose exit state you pass to the `if` command. Shell is weird ;-)